# How to carry out "replace into" operation in mongo nested array?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document below

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "timestamp" : 1564996848077,
    "version" : 1565080156000,
    "sku" : [
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "color" : "blue"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is to push three objects into the nested "sku" array.

```
{id：1, color: "red"}
{id: 2, color: "dark"} 
{id: 3, color: "white"}.
```

During the insert operations, update would be carried out if "id" exists in the array while insert would be done if "id" not exists. Like "replace into" in sql, I'd like to get the result below.

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "timestamp" : 1564996848077,
    "version" : 1565080156000,
    "sku" : [
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "color" : "white"  <== "update when 3 already exitst"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,           <== "insert"
            "color": "dark"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,           <== "insert"
            "color": "white"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried $set/$push/$addToSet but got no correct results.

Thanks a bunch for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you may use the command below:

```
db.collection.updateOne({id:3}, {$set:{id:3,color:"white"}, {upsert:true}})
```